# Как вытащить содержимое тега через preg_match_all?

Tags: preg_match, html, php

```
<div class="replies">

 <div class="comment">
   <div class="pros">ТЕСТ 1</div>
   <div class="contras">ТЕСТ 2</div>
   <p>ТЕКС ТЕКСТТ ЕКС ТЕКСТ ТЕКС ТЕКСТ ТЕКС ТЕКСТ</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

Как вытащить содержимое тега `<p> </p>`?

```
preg_match_all('/\<p\>(.+)\<\/p\>/isU', $content, $found3);
```

Не подходит т.к на старнице много тегов `<p>`, нужно, чтобы от только брал из блока

```
<div class="replies"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Как получать HTML элементы?

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: +1: парсинг HTML надо доверять парсеру.

Comment: simple html dom мне не подходит...

Comment: foreach($html->find('div') as $element)
        print_r($element);


Warning: mb_strpos(): Offset not contained in string in .../simple/simple_html_dom.php on line 1570